# Restricting the User Input to Alphabets

Tags: python

I'm a technical writer learning python. I wanted to write a program for validating the Name field input,as a practise, restricting the the user entries to alphabets.I saw a similar code for validating number (Age)field here, and adopted it for alphabets as below:

```
import string
```

`import re`

```
r = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+') 
print "WELCOME FOR NAME VERIFICATION. TYPE ALPHABETS ONLY!"
print raw_input("Your Name:")
x = r
if x == r:
    print x
elif x != r:
    print "Come on,'", x,"' can't be your name"
    print raw_input("Your Name:")
if 5<=len(x)<=10:
    print "Hi,", x, "!"
elif len(x)>10:
    print "Mmm,Your name is too long!"
elif len(x)<5:
    print "Alas, your name is too short!"

raw_input("Press 'Enter' to exit!")
```

I intend this code block to do two things. Namely, display the input prompt until the user inputs alphabets only as 'Name'. Then, if that happens, process the length of that input and display messages as coded. But, I get two problems that I could not solve even after a lot of attempts. Either, even the correct entries are rejected by exception code or wrong entries are also accepted and their length is processed.

Please help me to debug my code. And, is it  possible to do it without using the reg exp?

Comment: Please show us a case that fails.

Comment: Also, do you just mean characters from an alphabetic writing system (e.g. Roman or Devanagari), or do you mean characters from all writing systems intended for writing words (e.g. Chinese characters also)?

Comment: What is Mr. O'Reilly supposed to do? Or Mrs Leutheusser-Schnarrenberger?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python, you don't need regular expressions for this--there are included libraries which include functions which might help you. From this page on [String methods](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html), you can call `isalpha()`:

> Return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

I would suggest using `isalpha()` in your if-statement instead of `x==r`.

Comment: Yes, I've tried isalpha() and True/False also. Yet, the problems remain. I feel that I'm missing something. Probably, in  try-exception code lines. They don't work properly first. And, I just wanted to do this without using any/least built in functions - so that I get the hang of the programming logic!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're trying to do with

```
x = r
if x == r:
    etc
```

That condition will obviously always be true.

With your current code you were never saving the input, just printing it straight out.

**You also had no loop, it would only ask for the name twice, even if it was wrong both times it would continue.**

I think what you tried to do is this:

```
import string
import re

r = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+') 
print "WELCOME FOR NAME VERIFICATION. TYPE ALPHABETS ONLY!"
x = raw_input("Your Name:")

while not r.match(x):
    print "Come on,'", x,"' can't be your name"
    x = raw_input("Your Name:")

if 5<=len(x)<=10:
    print "Hi,", x, "!"
elif len(x)>10:
    print "Mmm,Your name is too long!"
elif len(x)<5:
    print "Alas, your name is too short!"

raw_input("Press 'Enter' to exit!")
```

Also, I would not use regex for this, try

```
while not x.isalpha():
```

Comment: Just as an aside: Try `r = float("NaN"); x = r; print (x == r)`

Comment: Hi Shawabawa, Yes, this is what I wanted. And, you're right in your comments too.I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: @Shawabawa, I got it through 'while not x.isalpha()' route also. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to do the following:

```
namefield = raw_input("Your Name: ")

if not namefield.isalpha():
    print "Please use only alpha charactors"

elif not 4<=len(namefield)<=10:
    print "Name must be more than 4 characters and less than 10"
else:
    print "hello" + namefield
```

`isalpha` will check to see if the whole string is only alpha characters. If it is, it will return True.

Comment: I adopted your suggestion as follows:

Comment: `if 5<=len(x)<=10` is a correct chained comparison in Python.

Comment: I adopted your suggestion as follows:                                                    x= raw_input("Your Name:") and if not x.isalpha():, as Python showed as namefield not defined. I also changed the 'if 5...' as suggested.The code worked beautifully for any first entry ( say, numbers), but worked incorrectly on second step. ie, it accepted wrong entry.

Comment: By the by, I use python 2.7 version along with IDLE.

Comment: @JanneKarila Thank you for that, I missed the `not` for the second statment and assumed it was the syntax and not me being silly :)

Comment: @K.Vee.Shanker. sorry about that, I forgot the `not` in the second statement, it should now work as advertised :), what was that about an undefined error?

Comment: Sorry, that unidentified error is due to my mistake. Yet, I continue to get the exception issue as stated earlier.

Comment: What is the type of the exception? What line does it happen on?

Comment: @downvoter I see no reason for this to be downvoted since it works perfectly for me and answers the OP's question.
@K.Vee.Shanker. Did you add the `not` to the second `elif` to fix the second step getting through?, what is your exception?

Comment: My adoption is shown here:
Please explain reasons for choosing ‘if not’, rather than the usual ‘elif’ for my guidance. Additionally, I want to say that my responses might be delayed due to my country being  5 ½  hrs ahead of GST.
Then, I also appreciate all the help given here.

Comment: Sorry, I press 'Enter' to move the next line that posts the msg                                                                                    import string
print "WELCOME FOR NAME VERIFICATION. TYPE ALPHABETS ONLY!"
x = raw_input("Your Name: ")
if not x.isalpha():
    print "Please use only alpha charactors"
    print raw_input("Your Name: ")
    if not 5<=len(x)<=10:
        print "Hi,", x, '!'
    if not len(x)>10:
        print "Mmm,Your name is too long!"
    else:
        print "Alas, your name is too short!"
raw_input("Press 'Enter' to exit!")

Comment: @K.Vee.Shanker. hmm I don't know what you are doing with that script. What I have given you is the bare bones of what you will need to check for `letters only` and `length`, I chose `if not` so that the error messages will display, `if not` is the same as `if !()`

Comment: Thanks Serdalis. Your code is elegant, as it is. I tried to incorporate a try-exception to insist on right input. Yet, I appreciate your follow up for resolution.                                                                        While I'm happy that my vexatious problem is solved, I also thank for all the suggestions here.