# Alphabet check as input

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I just start learning python today and get to apply what I learning on a flash cards program, I want to ask the user for their name, and only accept alphabet without numbers or symbols, I've tried several ways but there is something I am missing in my attempts. Here is what I did so far.

```
yname = raw_input('Your Name ?: ')
if yname.isdigit():
    print ('{0}, can\'t be your name!'.format(yname))
    print "Please use alphbetic characters only!."
    yname = raw_input("Enter your name:?")
    print "Welcome %s !" %yname
```

but I figured in this one is if the user input any character more than one time it will eventually continue...So I did this instead.

```
yname = raw_input("EnterName").isalpha()
while yname == True:
    if yname == yname.isalpha():
        print "Welcome %s " %(yname)
else:
    if yname == yname.isdigit():
        print ("Name must be alphabetical only!")
        yname = raw_input('Enter Name:').isalpha()
```

This while loop goes on forever, as well as I tried (-) and (+) the raw input variable as I've seen in some tutorials. So I thought of using while loop.

```
name = raw_input("your name"):
while True:
    if name > 0 and name.isalpha():
        print "Hi %s " %name
    elif name < 0 and name.isdigit():
        print "Name must be Alphabet characters only!"
try:
    name != name.isalpha():
except (ValueError):
     print "Something went wrong"
```

Comment: `name < 0 and name.isdigit():` will never happen, use or: `name < 0 or name.isdigit():`. Also, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800060/restricting-the-user-input-to-alphabets

Comment: Good source dude. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check for both alphabet in the raw_input and check for the length of the name as I see you tried to do in your last try.

```
import string
import re

name = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+') #This will check for alphabet.
yname = raw_input("Your Name:") #ask the user for input.

while not name.match(yname): 
    print "invalid characters"
    yname = raw_input("Your Name:")
if 5<=len(yname)<=10:
    print "Hi,", yname, "!"
elif len(yname)>10:
    print "too long!"
elif len(yname)<5:
    print "too short!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange your last attempt a bit to get what you want:

```
while True:
    name = raw_input("your name") # ask inside the loop
    if name and name.isalpha():
        print "Hi %s " %name
        break # leave the loop if done
    elif name and name.isdigit():
        print "Name must be Alphabet characters only!"
    else:
        print "Please enter something"
```

Note that `if name` will be `True` if `name != ""`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [regexes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
regex = re.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$")

valid_name = False
while not valid_name:
   user_name = raw_input("EnterName")
   if not regex.search(user_name):
        print "this can't be your name"
    else:
        print "Hi there, {0}".format(user_name)
        valid_name = True
```

Also, please take note that [programmers often make false assumptions about human names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

*Edit:* as an alternative you can skip compiling a regex and just use the pattern in place:

```
if not re.search("^[a-zA-Z]+$", user_name):
    ...
```

However, since you're doing it in a loop compiled version would have slightly better performance, since `re.search` actually compiles a regex behind the scenes each time invoked.

Also, please note I've changed `match` to `search` and slightly modified a regex since there're [some differences](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) and it appears tome me that `search` suits your situation more.

Comment: Thanks @J0HN, can we use the re.compile("[a-ZA-Z]+") directly in the "if" without assigning it to a variable -> regex and just write, if not re.compile("[a-zA-Z]").match(user_name):

Comment: @user3510177 not exactly like you wrote, but yes. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
while not name.isalpha():
    print 'Invaid characters in name'
    name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
```