# How can I make an error message if numbers are entered in python

Tags: python

I'm making a Pizza menu and I need an error message to pop up if there are numbers enetered for the customers name and so on

Comment: type this "python validate data entry" into a search engine...followed by "python message box"  - it's that easy.....

Comment: Are you working on a web page or command line or..?  Have some sample code you could post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting the User Input to Alphabets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800060/restricting-the-user-input-to-alphabets)

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have the name in a variable, you could do the following:

```
#defining a name ...
name = 'Bill Joe'
if name.isalpha():
    #do what you want ...
else:
    #return or print an error ...
```

You should look through

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalpha#str.isalpha

Answer (score 0):

You should use isalpha() to ensure the name is entered in as all characters. There are other checks you can perform to make sure the input is exactly as you want it, but as a start, just make sure everything is text.

Example:

`Customer_Name = input("Please enter your name: ")
if Customer_Name.isalpha():
    #start your program here if the input is text
else:
    Customer_Name = input("Please enter a valid name: ")`

You can wrap this in a loop to give them a shot at trying a few times before you quit on them as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
if customer[0] =="p":
    customer.append(input("Customer Name:"))
if customer[0] =="d":
    customer.append(input("Customer Name:"))
    customer.append(input("Address:"))
    customer.append(input("Phone No:"))
```

If anything but p or d are entered I need an error message to pop up saying 'Input Error' or something